# iframe screen mess up

Tags: javascript, iframe

I am trying to display a yahoo video inside a javascript created popup using an iframe. The popup get displayed perfectly and the video is playable in iframe but when i close the popup the popup get closed but the video image remains on the screnn till i perform a page refresh. I am using the followinf code

```
<iframe width="280" height="190" frameborder="0" src="https://docs.google.com/file/d/filename/preview"></iframe>
```

i have also tried

```
sandbox="allow-same-origin allow-scripts allow-popups allow-forms"
```

but using this problem of screen mess up gets resolved but no video gets displayed in the popup.

The whole function which creates popup is shown below

```
function helpPopup(el) {
var height = (window.innerHeight ? (window.innerHeight) * 3 / 4 : 640);
var helpDialog = new YAHOO.widget.Dialog('help', {
        width: (window.innerWidth ? (window.innerWidth) / 2 : '480')+'px',
        height: height+'px',
        fixedcenter: true,
        effect: {
                effect: YAHOO.widget.ContainerEffect.FADE,
                duration: 0.25
        },
        modal: true,
        visible: false,
        draggable: true
});

helpDialog.setHeader("Help");
var content="";
content = '<div style="overflow: auto; height: '+(height-50)+'px">'+
'<table><tr><td>This is a help popup you can see the video below for demonstation purposes</td></tr></table>'+
'<br><br><br><p><iframe width="280" height="190" frameborder="0" src="https://docs.google.com/file/d/xxxxxxxxx/preview"></iframe></p>'+        
'</div>';
helpDialog.setBody(content);
helpDialog.cfg.queueProperty('keylisteners', new YAHOO.util.KeyListener(
        document,
        { keys : 27 },
        {
                fn: function() { this.hide(); },
                scope: helpDialog,
                correctScope:true
        }
));

helpDialog.render(document.body);
helpDialog.show();
```

}

Any help in resolving the problem of displaying video and get closed without messing up screen  will be appreciated!

Comment: This is a browser-specific issue. Also, please add the code which closes the popup to your question.

Comment: Does this happen in Chrome only?

Comment: No almost in all browsers i haved mostly in IE and Chromium